# T-SQL get rows with with difference in days more than 30 days between the rows with every 30 days or more mark resetting the pivot date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a sample table (TABLE) like the below

| MemberKey | VisitStartDate |
| --- | --- |
| 34432 | 2022-01-28 |
| 34432 | 2022-03-22 |
| 34432 | 2022-04-13 |
| 34432 | 2022-04-27 |
| 34432 | 2022-08-10 |
| 34432 | 2022-08-22 |
| 34432 | 2022-11-22 |

Based on the record set above, the first time the difference between the visit dates is more than 30 days is 2022-03-22. After this date the next time the difference is more than 30 days is 2022-04-27 (Based on the date 03-22-2022). After that the next time we have 30 days or more visit is 08-10-2022 and then based on that date we have 2022-11-22. So every time we hit the more than 30 day visit mark the pivot date to check the next 30 days change to that new date. I have the following code done to group it but it is not exactly correct.

```
SELECT
    MemberKey
    ,group_id
    ,VisitStartDate
    ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,LAG(VisitStartDate,1)OVER(PARTITION BY MemberKey,group_id ORDER BY VisitStartDate),VisitStartDate) >30 THEN VisitStartDate END AS NextVisitDate
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
             MemberKey
            ,group_id
            ,VisitStartDate
            ,FIRST_VALUE(VisitStartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberKey, group_id ORDER BY VisitStartDate DESC) - FIRST_VALUE(VisitStartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberKey, group_id ORDER BY VisitStartDate) AS diff
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    MemberKey
                    ,VisitStartDate
                    ,SUM(group_id) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberKey ORDER BY VisitStartDate) AS group_id
                FROM 
                    (
                        SELECT
                            MemberKey
                            ,VisitStartDate
                            ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,LAG(VisitStartDate, 1, VisitStartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberKey ORDER BY VisitStartDate),VisitStartDate) > 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS group_id
                        FROM
                            Table   
                        WHERE
                            MemberKey = 34432
                    ) S
            ) S
    ) A
```

Would be great if someone can help me get the solution correctly. I have only given an example of a MemberKey but this needs to work across 100K members.

Thanks!

Comment: Why 2022-04-27 is based on 2022-03-22 but not 2022-04-13? I don't quite get what you try to achieve. It would be easier if you provide your expected SQL result.

Comment: So Date1 is the first date. Date2 is the first date more than 30 days after Date1. DateN is the first date more than 30 days after Date<N-1>. The preceding is to be calculated independently for each distinct MemberKey. Is that correct?

Comment: It sounds like the general case will either require iteration, or perhaps a clever recursive CTE.

Comment: Yes that is correct. That is why the new 30 day date keeps moving as we hit the new date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a achieved by building up a query using several Common Table Expressions (CTEs) including a recursive one that:

1. Selects the first visit for each member
2. Calculates the next >30 day visit for each record, and
3. Recursively chains the results together.

```
;WITH FirstVisit AS (
    -- First visit for each member
    SELECT V.MemberKey, MIN(V.VisitStartDate) AS VisitStartDate
    FROM Visits V
    GROUP BY V.MemberKey
), FollowingVisits AS (
    -- For each visit, use CROSS APPLY to select the next >30 day visit
    -- for the same member
    SELECT V.MemberKey, V.VisitStartDate, VNEXT.VisitStartDate AS NextVisitStartDate
    FROM Visits V
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 V2.*
        FROM Visits V2
        WHERE V2.MemberKey = V.MemberKey
        AND V2.VisitStartDate > DATEADD(day, 30, V.VisitStartDate)
        ORDER BY V2.VisitStartDate
    ) VNEXT
), VisitChain AS (
    -- Recursive CTE that includes the first visit for each member plus all of the
    -- previously calculated >30 day following visits
    SELECT V.MemberKey, V.VisitStartDate
    FROM FirstVisit V
    UNION ALL
    SELECT FV.MemberKey, FV.NextVisitStartDate AS VisitStartDate
    FROM VisitChain VC
    JOIN FollowingVisits FV
        ON FV.MemberKey = VC.MemberKey
        AND FV.VisitStartDate = VC.VisitStartDate
)
SELECT *
FROM VisitChain VC
ORDER BY VC.MemberKey, VC.VisitStartDate
```

Using the supplied sample data plus additional data for another member who visits daily for 1000 days, the following results are obtained:

| MemberKey | VisitStartDate |
| --- | --- |
| 34432 | 2022-01-28 |
| 34432 | 2022-03-22 |
| 34432 | 2022-04-27 |
| 34432 | 2022-08-10 |
| 34432 | 2022-11-22 |
| 99999 | 2021-01-15 |
| 99999 | 2021-02-15 |
| 99999 | 2021-03-18 |
| 99999 | 2021-04-18 |
| 99999 | 2021-05-19 |
| ... | ... |
| 99999 | 2023-10-04 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KB6ZR1HG).

Initially, I wasn't sure about the performance of the recursive CTE, but the execution was very fast for the test data I used.

Comment: Classic! I normally don't use CROSS APPLY in my queries. But this is golden and very well explained solution! Thank you T N. Much Appreciated. I will test this across all my established member base and see hoe it goes. Recursive CTE rocks!

Comment: I find CROSS APPLY valuable in two situations: (1) When for each row in your query you need to look up the one "best" related row `CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ... FROM related ... ORDER BY ...) X` and when I want to calculate one or more intermediate values for use (and reuse) in subsequent calculations and/or final select list `CROSS APPLY (SELECT expression, expression, ...) X`.

Comment: This is the first time I've used a recursive CTE to chain together linked rows like a linked-list. I was actually surprised it worked.